# Python screen sharing with flask app in python

Tags: python, sockets, flask, screensharing

I am using flask app for screen sharing when I run the script it neither show screen sharing nor it gives any error but its does not stop loading, and shows nothing but white screen. It should have shown the screen on web.

python code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/screen_sharing')
def screen_sharing():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('192.168.1.112', 5000))
    def generate_frames():
        while True:
            try:
                data = b''
                while True:
                    packet = client_socket.recv(4096)
                    if not packet:
                        break
                    data += packet
                frame = np.frombuffer(zlib.decompress(data), dtype=np.uint8)
                frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, 1)
                
                if frame is not None:
                    _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                    frame = buffer.tobytes()
                    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
                else:
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
                break
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen_thread = threading.Thread(target=screen_sharing)
    screen_thread.start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

HTML code for web interface:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100vh;
            height: auto;
        }
        .screen{
            /* background: #ff6860; */
            border: 1px solid #474e5d;
            border-radius: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
<head>
    <title>Screen Sharing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <img class="screen" src="{{ url_for('screen_sharing') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
      
    </script>
</html>
```

Output:
"
** Serving Flask app '**main**'

- Debug mode: off
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
- Running on http://192.168.1.112:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit*
  "

What is it that I am doing wrong in this code,

Comment: `if not packet: break` only breaks if the socket is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your previous response. I've made the changes to the code by checking the length of the received packet i.e., (`if len(packet) == 0:` instead of `if not packet: break`) before breaking out of the inner loop. However, the issue with continuous loading and a blank screen persists. Is there any changes you would recommend to change in the code?

Comment: You only get a length of 0 if the socket is closed as well.  You have to send the length of the packet in some way, such as binary `struct.pack('<i', length()` or newline-terminated text `f'{length}\n'`, **then** send the packet.  On the receiver, read the length and then the packet.

Answer (score 1):

In TCP, the data is a byte stream, **not** messages.  `recv(n)` receives either 0 (socket closed) or 1-n bytes.  You must check the return value's length and buffer it until you have the amount requested.

If your packets are all the same size this is relatively easy, but if they vary you need have a protocol to determine the framing of packets.  One way is to send the length and then the packet.

Buffering can be handled by wrapping the socket in [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile).  Then the TCP stream will act more like a file, with `.readline()` and `.read(n)` methods.  `.read(n)` will wait until it receives n bytes or an error or end-of-file is encountered, whereas `socket.recv(n)` will give you whatever is in the TCP buffers (always at least 1 byte if the socket isn't closed, but up to n bytes depending on data availability).

Simple example that can send any blob of packet data:

```py
import socket
import threading

class PacketError(Exception): pass

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', 5000))
    s.listen()
    print('Server started...')
    with s:
        while running:
            c, a = s.accept()
            # Wrap client in binary file-like object
            with c, c.makefile('rb') as infile:
                while True:
                    header = infile.readline()
                    if not header: break
                    length = int(header)
                    data = infile.read(length)
                    if len(data) != length:
                        raise PacketError('incomplete packet')
                    print(data)

running = True
t = threading.Thread(target=server)
t.start()

# Protocol: send length as decimal text terminated by newline,
# then exactly "length" data.
def send_data(sock, data):
    sock.sendall(f'{len(data)}\n'.encode())
    sock.sendall(data)

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    send_data(s, b'hello, world!')
    send_data(s, b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    send_data(s, b'she sells seashells by the seashore')

running = False  # Signal server to exit
t.join()         # Wait for thread to exit
print('Server exited.')
```

Output:

```
Server started...
b'hello, world!'
b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
b'she sells seashells by the seashore'
Server exited.
```